What are the acceptable properties for a folder in the Desmos API?
I'm using the Desmos API to visualise some data from an application I'm testing. I have a fair number of formulas that I'd like to group meaningfully, and I know in the UI I can use folders for that.
Desmos' API docs say that setExpression can take a type property, but claim it can only be expression (which is the default) or table – though further down it becomes evident that it can also be text.
I have succeeded in creating a folder with setExpression({ type: 'folder' }), so that apparently works as well; but I have been unable to rename the folder (name, text, title, and folderName all have no effect, it remains "Untitled folder"), and I can't figure out how to put other expressions into it either.
I have also put the things into the state I want using the UI, and grabbed them using getState() – they look, in part, like this:
"expressions": {
  "list": [
    {
      "type": "folder",
      "id": "gradients",
      "title": "Gradients" // This is significant
    },
    {
      "type": "expression",
      "id": "gradient",
      "folderId": "gradients", // This is significant
      "color": "#2d70b3",
      "latex": "\\Delta=y_1\\left[1...\\right]-y_1\\left[0...\\right]",
      "hidden": true
    }, // ...

... but setting these values using setExpression() does not have the desired effects either.
Google is no help. Is this community up to the challenge?

As you said, there isn't a way to modify folders directly from setExpression, but you could use setState() and getState(). I am running this directly through the console, however, it should be similar-ish to the API. Here is a function, that can modify the title of a folder
function SetfolderTitle(id, title){
    let state = Calc.getState();
    for (var i in state.expressions.list){
        if(state.expressions.list[i].id == id){
            state.expressions.list[i].title = title
            break;
        }
    }
    Calc.setState(state)
}

As for adding a expression to it, you can do a similar thing:
function AddExpression(FolderId, id){
    let state = Calc.getState();
    for (var i in state.expressions.list){
        if(state.expressions.list[i].id == id){
            state.expressions.list[i]["folderId"] = FolderId
            break;
        }
    }
    Calc.setState(state)
}

There are probably easier ways of doing this, but I am terrible at Javascript.
